# Cant see desktop on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, dell

*emphasized text*I just tried to upgrade ubuntu 14 to 16 on my laptop and the desktop doesn't show up. Instead it shows this...

[image: See here]

update: I just gave up on 16 and reinstalled 14

Answer (score 1):

You can try typing `startx` in the terminal and see if that works.

Comment: It shows my wallpaper and a current that looks like an "x". I can right click and a menu asking New folder, Open terminal, organize desktop by name, and keep aligned(checked) show up. I can make a new folder but can't open a terminal. What now?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what it looks like?